# How to add a count value at the end of each pattern found using sed

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with pattern:

```
START_BIT_VAL  somedata
somedata
START_BIT_VAL  somedata
somedata
START_BIT_VAL somedata
SOMEDATA
```

I want to replace this pattern with:

```
START_BIT_VAL_0  somedata
somedata
START_BIT_VAL_1 somedata
somedata
START_BIT_VAL_2  somedata
SOMEDATA
```

The occurrence of the instance should be appended after the matched pattern.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
perl -lne 'END {print $cnt } map ++$cnt, s/START_BIT_VAL/START_BIT_VAL_$cnt/g' <file_name>
```

The problem is that I am just getting the output as the number but no replacement is happening.

Comment: You need to tell us what you have tried and what problems you are having.

Comment: i tried this perl -lne 'END {print $cnt } map ++$cnt, s/START_BIT_VAL/START_BIT_VAL_$cnt/g' <file_name>

Comment: i am just getting the output as the number but no replacement is happening

Comment: @Rajgopal You should [edit] your post to include what you've tried.

Comment: You need to add the `-i` option, or switch from `-n` to `-p`

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {c=0} {if ($1=="START_BIT_VAL") {$1=$1c; c++}; print}' file
```

Output:

```
START_BIT_VAL0 somedata
somedata
START_BIT_VAL1 somedata
somedata
START_BIT_VAL2 somedata
SOMEDATA
```

Comment: works for OP's example, but should be noted that, this does slightly different from OP's requirement: `The occurrence of the instance should be appended after the matched pattern` Because this is only checking the first Field, not each match. The matched string could be located in any Fields or crossing Field. Like Pattern `[0-9]+ .*`